# Extract Fields from a Json String in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to extract the  ids from each company_id from the following Json String

```
String test = ["{\"company_id\":4100,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":4045,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":2979,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}"]
```

I am very new to working with Json. This is what I have so far:

```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(test);
   JSONObject newJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("company_id");
   System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
   jsonObject = new JSONObject(newJSON.toString());
```

I am stuck here because I honestly do not know how would I extract the company_id.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Using Jackson or Gson is usually easier.

Comment: Could you please provide an example using Gson, or a Link to some good examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     String test = ["{\"company_id\":4100,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":4045,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}","{\"company_id\":2979,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}"]       

     JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();         
     Object obj = parser.parse(test);
     JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
     System.out.println(array.get("company_id"));
```

Comment: you add it please ,JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Comment: read the following link :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a object array. I think you can get you answer using following way.

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

  String company_id=array.getJSONObject(i).getString("company_id");

}
```