# How do I obtain only View count from the following JSON Array?

Tags: java, json

Here is the JSON response of a video for youtube data analytics:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/nKD2hgTXHwAf_Y8YHghPkBlZJcs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/GLcJdYlEeecN5amO819w0A1mSqU\"",
   "id": "PK_HFb8tkUs",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-03-14T01:52:34.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCHqC-yWZ1kri4YzwRSt6RGQ",
    "title": "Full Speech: Donald Trump HUGE Rally in Boca Raton, FL (3-13-16)",
    "description": "Sunday, March 13, 2016: GOP Presidential candidate Donald Trump held a campaign rally in Boca Raton, FL at Sunset Cove Amphitheater and spoke to a massive crowd of tens of thousands of supporters.\n\nFull Speech: Donald Trump Rally in Boca Raton, FL (3-13-16)",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PK_HFb8tkUs/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PK_HFb8tkUs/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PK_HFb8tkUs/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PK_HFb8tkUs/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Right Side Broadcasting",
    "tags": [
     "Donald Trump",
     "Live Stream",
     "Boca Raton",
     "Florida",
     "Rally",
     "Speech",
     "Politics",
     "Republican Party"
    ],
    "categoryId": "25",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Full Speech: Donald Trump HUGE Rally in Boca Raton, FL (3-13-16)",
     "description": "Sunday, March 13, 2016: GOP Presidential candidate Donald Trump held a campaign rally in Boca Raton, FL at Sunset Cove Amphitheater and spoke to a massive crowd of tens of thousands of supporters.\n\nFull Speech: Donald Trump Rally in Boca Raton, FL (3-13-16)"
    },
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "en"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT2H41M2S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true
   },
   "status": {
    "uploadStatus": "processed",
    "privacyStatus": "public",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "371675",
    "likeCount": "7592",
    "dislikeCount": "586",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "1397"
   }
  }
 ]
```

I would only like to extract the viewCount for example from the above response. How do I do that in Java? I have obtained the above response in a string but how do I extract just those single values like viewCount? An example is well appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Fields from a Json String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33470645/extract-fields-from-a-json-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to traverse the JSON array to get the viewCount field. I can't give you the exact code to use as you have not told us what JSON library you are using, but here's some pseudocode.

```
// If json is the object containing the JSON data
viewCount = json["items"][0]["statistics"]["viewCount"];
```

From the "items" array, you get the first element, then the "statistics" object from that element, then the "viewCount" field from the statistics object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
String jsonString="";
JsonParser jParser= Json.createParser(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes()));
while(jParser.hasNext()){
    if(jParser.next()==Event.KEY_NAME){
        if(jParser.getString().equals("viewCount")){
            jParser.next();
            System.out.println(jParser.getString());
        }
    }
}
```

The library should be imported correctly. Please refer - 
https://jsonp.java.net/download.html.